# htaccess force / to use index.php despite other rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

htaccess explicitly redirect `/` to `index.php` despite other rules that map `/something` to `another.php?q=something`.

The conflicting rule is `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ another.php?q=$1 [QSA]`. I tried `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php [QSA]` above the conflicting rule but that breaks mapping properly to `another.php`.

Any ideas of how to write the correct htaccess rule?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DirectoryIndex` to handle `/`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ another.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```